# Coordinate naming in custom Tikz package

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

I want to make my own Tikz library/package or just a set of commands for making hydraulic diagrams within the Tikz environment. Say I want to draw a valve like (b) with the notation for the nodes in (a) (red)

[image: Valve example with coordinate names]

I want to write something like

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (1,1) valve[name = V, ports = 4, type = 1];
  \draw[-o] (0,0) -| (V1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with more options than those listed such as `rotate`, `scale`, etc.

Both possible solutions and guidance to further reading is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use a `pic`.

Comment: Welcome! A `pic` would indeed be good here. The way I usually create `pic`s when I'm not quite sure what I'm doing (which is usually the case), I start by just trying to draw a one-off instance of the thing I want. That is, I don't worry about options and re-using things and all the rest of it. I just concentrate on drawing, say, a single valve. Then I create some styles so that I can customise that single valve and I use the styles to define the valve. Now I've got something where I can twiddle the output without altering the code for the valve. Finally, I create a pic from it.

Comment: But before you do anything else, get yourself a better picture of the thing you want to draw. At least a bigger one so you can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You might start by looking at the circuits library of tikz and circuitikz (which is a lot easier to create components for).